# Add and modify mulitple constraints in a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

How do I add more than one constraint on tableViewCell labels?

I tried with `NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat`, it only works for the first time then when I scroll down the tableview, it resets back to default.

I want the constraints to be changed depending on user uploads a image or not.

If pic is uploaded then it will show the set imageView to true then the label (user's comment). If user uploads nothing but texts, just show label (user's comment) starting from left and imageView to hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case if anyone wants to know. what i did. 
untick those autolayout and auto-sizing from the main storyboard. 
and i added CGRectMake and CGPointMake programmatically to the items in custom cell worked like a charm. now i have no problem changing the positions in cell.
if anyone who is getting a lot of constraints errors in console box. please try this way. i dont get anymore errors with my constraints.